# Jest error: "Your focus-trap must have at least one container with at least one tabbable node in it at all times"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest to write tests for React Components. I can't fix a bug in a component test. I tried to add focus on the element to the test code:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('continue')).toHaveFocus());
```

But it didn't work. How to solve this error?

This is the component code:

```
function SuccessCommentAddPopup({onSuccessComment}: SuccessCommentAddPopupProps): JSX.Element {
 
  return (
    <AriaModal
      titleText='add comment success'
      initialFocus="#continue"
    >
      <div style={{position: 'relative', width: '550px', height: '410px', marginBottom: '50px'}}>
        <div className={style.modal}>
          <div className={style.modalWrapper}>
            <div className={style.modalOverlay} data-close-modal></div>
            <div className={style.modalContent}>
              <svg className={style.modalIcon} width="26" height="20" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlinkHref="#icon-success"></use>
              </svg>
              <p className={style.modalMessage}>Thank's a lot!</p>
              <div className={style.modalButtonContainer}>
                <button
                  id='continue'
                  data-testid='continue'
                  className={style.modalButton}
                  onClick={()=>{
                    onSuccessComment(false);
                  }}
                >
                Close
                </button>
              </div>
              <button
                className={style.modalCloseBtn}
                type="button"
                aria-label="Close"
                onClick={()=>{
                  onSuccessComment(false);
                }}
              >
                <span className={style.buttonCrossIcon}>
                </span><span className={style.modalCloseBtninteractiveArea}></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </AriaModal>
  );
}

export default SuccessCommentAddPopup;
```

This is the test code:

```
const history = createMemoryHistory();
history.push('/guitars/1');


describe('Component: SuccessCommentAddPopup', () => {
  it('Компонент отрисовывается корректно', async () => {
    render(
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <SuccessCommentAddPopup
          onSuccessComment={jest.fn()}
        />
      </HistoryRouter>,
    );
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('continue')).toHaveFocus());
    expect(screen.getByText('Спасибо за ваш отзыв!')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to mock `tabbable` module. Check this [link](https://github.com/focus-trap/tabbable#testing-in-jsdom)

Comment: Do you know what is the way to mock it with vite. I can't seem to do it

Answer (score 4):

@Ararat is correct. I solved this by mocking out tabbable: https://github.com/focus-trap/tabbable#testing-in-jsdom

added: ./**mocks**/tabable.js with the following:

```js
// __mocks__/tabbable.js

const lib = jest.requireActual('tabbable');

const tabbable = {
   ...lib,
   tabbable: (node, options) => lib.tabbable(node, { ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
   focusable: (node, options) => lib.focusable(node, { ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
   isFocusable: (node, options) => lib.isFocusable(node, { ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
   isTabbable: (node, options) => lib.isTabbable(node, { ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
};

module.exports = tabbable;
```

I spent a lot of time figuring this out, thats why im sharing! I was using useFocusTrap from @vueUs in a vue 3 project and my vue-testing-library component tests broke because of this missing!

Comment: Do you know how to mock that with vitests. I do not have any luck with the __mocks__ folder

Answer (score 1):

You need to create tabbanle.js file inside your `__mocks__` folder, now if you do not have the folder in you IDE look for `__test__` folder in my repository I added the folder in the `src/server/models/__mocks__/tabbable.js`
yes it is similar to the other answer but where do create the folder information was missing and it took me long time to figure it out hence adding here

And add the below code in that file.

```
// __mocks__/tabbable.js

const lib = jest.requireActual('tabbable');

const tabbable = {
...lib,
tabbable: (node, options) => lib.tabbable(node, { 
 ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
 focusable: (node, options) => lib.focusable(node, { 
 ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
 isFocusable: (node, options) => lib.isFocusable(node, { 
 ...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
 isTabbable: (node, options) => lib.isTabbable(node, { 
...options, displayCheck: 'none' }),
 };

 module.exports = tabbable;
```

just save the file and run your tests again and the error would have magically disappeared.
I have also written a post on all other jest errors after the update you can check here here https://medium.com/@arianallami/jest-update-466f08181d06

Comment: Hello @Arian Al Lami, I added a new file with this tabbable stuff, so I'm still getting this error, then I tried to added an import from this file like: `import { tabbable } from '../test/__mock__/tabbable' ;`
what must be wrong?

Comment: you don't need to do any import as long as the file exists in the right location it will work

Comment: what would be the correct location? just to be more aligned, the only thing I did was create a new file with these settings, jest works normally with other tests.

Comment: In my case i created a folder called __mocks__ and inside it i created the file tabbable.js in side the models folder so check if you have models folder ?  if not check if u have a folder called __tests__ in my case that folder is in models folders too

Answer (score 0):

We should find which branch of this function returns true https://github.com/focus-trap/tabbable/blob/master/src/index.js#L367

In my case it was

```
if (isNodeAttached(node)) {
  // this works wherever the node is: if there's at least one client rect, it's
  //  somehow displayed; it also covers the CSS 'display: contents' case where the
  //  node itself is hidden in place of its contents; and there's no need to search
  //  up the hierarchy either
  return !node.getClientRects().length;
}
```

So, we need to mock it like so

```
const getClientRects = HTMLElement.prototype.getClientRects
HTMLElement.prototype.getClientRects = function () {
  return {
    ...getClientRects.apply(this),
    length: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For vite, you can specify when mounting the component directly, as per [this comment](https://github.com/focus-trap/focus-trap-react/issues/1002#issuecomment-1564573419):

```js
<FocusTrap
  focusTrapOptions={{
    ...,
    tabbableOptions: {
      displayCheck: TEST_ENV ? 'none' : 'whatever you normally set it to, or undefined for the default'
    }
  }}
>
  <button>I'm trapped</button>
</FocusTrap>
```

This won't help with dependencies of dependencies in vite though.